# File listed but not present

Tags: ls, void-linux

I am running 64-bit [KLV-Airedale](https://forum.puppylinux.com/viewtopic.php?t=6961) (a fork of Void Linux). When I try to do `ls /usr/lib64/gio/modules/libgioenvironmentproxy.so`, I get-

```
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib64/gio/modules/libgioenvironmentproxy.so': No such file or directory
```

But I can see `libgioenvironmentproxy.so` present in directory `/usr/lib64/gio/modules/`. When I try to do `ls -l /usr/lib64/gio/modules/` I get-

```
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib64/gio/modules/libgioenvironmentproxy.so': No such file or directory
total 556
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    318 Oct  1 04:28 giomodule.cache
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  55280 Apr  9  2021 libdconfsettings.so
c????????? ? ?    ?         ?            ? libgioenvironmentproxy.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  22440 Sep 26 22:18 libgiognomeproxy.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 124968 Sep 26 22:18 libgiognutls.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  18344 Sep 26 22:18 libgiolibproxy.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 108544 Jul  5 22:12 libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 203016 Jul  5 22:12 libgvfsdbus.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  34728 Dec 31  2020 libxfconfgsettingsbackend.so
```

I can't understand why is this like this? What does `ls -l` show about the status of `libgioenvironmentproxy.so`?

And yes, doing `xbps-install -f gnutls gnutls-devel` doesn't help.

Please help!

Comment: The `c` at the beginning of that line would indicate that the file is a "character special" inode, which would make no sense. Along with the rest of the odd characters in that entry it might be an indication that you have a corrupted filesystem. I would recommend shutting down and forcing an `fsck` on that disk.

Comment: Running fsck on the disk did did something (that is it reported and corrected some errors). But no luck, `/usr/lib64/gio/modules/libgioenvironmentproxy.so` is as it is. Maybe a KLV bug (Should try asking help on that forum)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. I posted the same question in KLV-Airedale forum. Seems to be rather a bug. I resolved the issue by running in a terminal- `xbps-install -f glib-networking`.